# How to spawn a process as another user on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

I have a Perl script and I need to run it as another user on the local box.  It's a testing machine, so no real security—I would use hammer if it worked.

What I've tried so far is

```
$cmd = 'runas /user:tester01 "perl delegated.pl"';
system($cmd) == 0
    or die "could not spawn process as tester01: $!";
```

but that does not work: it asks for password interactively. (Piping `echo password` into the `runas` failed as well.)

How should I achieve it from within Perl script?  Or should I do something else before that `system "runas..."` part?

I know I can use PsExec, but I'd prefer Windows native solution.  Currently the boxes it should work on are Windows 7 and Windows XP, but other Windows OS might be added later.

Comment: You can try `Expect` perl module that allows a script to work with interactive programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to play with WinAPI to send a password into the spawned shell (for example, [Win32::GuiTest](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aGuiTest) SendKeys method might be useful), you'd better use PsExec. ) [This thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/29/271551.aspx) is a bit old, but it still describes Microsoft policy pretty well, I guess.

Comment: I finally chose PsExec to do my job. I could make `runas` + Win32::GuiTest run, but unfortunately not very reliably, especially if there was larger amount of processes to be spawned quickly.

Comment: (Again the old rule for scripting on Windows proved: most "native" way on Windows is avoiding the native ways)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how your code would go:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::GuiTest qw[ SendKeys ];

system 1, q[runas /user:machinename\username "perl scriptname.pl"];

SendKeys( 'password~');
```

See [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/~karasik/Win32-GuiTest-1.58/lib/Win32/GuiTest.pm#Functions) documentation for more details on SendKeys().

Comment: However, this does not really fit for scripting, i.e. (a) you need to avoid interaction, and (b) things seem to get very messy as long as this snippet is put into a loop or so. Probably more playing with `Win32::GuiTest` could help, though...

Comment: @AloisMahdal - Welcome and Thanks.I will check on how to avoid enter.

Comment: After looking at first few lines of [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/~karasik/Win32-GuiTest-1.58/lib/Win32/GuiTest.pm#Functions) I could finally make it work.  The secret s the tilde (`~`) that does *press* the [Enter] for you.

Comment: Still, though, *sometimes* some of iterations in the loop still fail (refusing the password), sometimes all pass. Reasons yet unknown...est

Comment: @AloisMahdal- You can also use `SendKeys("{ENTER}");` to avoid the Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
system($cmd) == 0
    or die "could not spawn process as tester01: $!";
```

In your code `$cmd==0` will evaluate to 1 since `$cmd` will convert to the number 0 and `0==0`, then `system` will be passed 1 and try to run it as a command.

You should `use warnings;` it would have reported an issue when `$cmd` was implicitly converted to a number.

Comment: Thanks, that was just a typo in my example. Of course I do `use warnings;` :)